# Console.log() isn't logging in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have console.log() at some places in my code but none of the console.logs() in my react code is working. I am pasting some of them for your reference.Login.jsx http://pastebin.com/GnK5GYui and Main.jsx here http://pastebin.com/nLBgTQwC. If you want i can post other parts of the project.

Answer (score 5):

use console.log() outside return statement.
use in this way.

```
 render() {
   console.log('In Render')
   return (
  <div> In Render </div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Its not `console.logs()`,its `console.log()`.

```
render(){
console.log('In Render')
  return ()
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo I'm using console.log()

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma on line 32 in http://pastebin.com/GnK5GYui

```
console.log('In Render'),
```