# setTimeout seems to be getting shorter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, chatbot

I am writing a chatbot application and wanted to catch multiple user inputs by blurring out of the input field and focussing back in after 3 seconds (when the bot responded).

I used setTimeout for this and it works the first time but it seems to get shorter after calling the function multiple times.

The code I used is in a React chat widget and looks like this:

```js
handleKeyPress = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && this.input.value.replace(/\s/g, "")) {
        this.input.blur();
        this.say(this.input.value);
        // Reset input value
        this.input.value = "";
        this.refocus(document.getElementById('userText'));
    }
};

refocus = (element: HTMLElement) => {
    var time = setTimeout(function() {
        element.focus();
    }, 3000);
};
```

In this code I use a setTimeout after sending the message to the backend bot application so that the bot has some time to answer.

I can't figure out why this is not working and could really use some suggestions...

Comment: You're calling `setTimeout()` then immediately `clearTimeout()` on the same timeout that has just assigned

Comment: That only gets called after the setTimeout is done I figured. Anyway I did it without the clear at first and didn't work. Updated my question!

Comment: What makes you think the setTimeout is shorter than it is supposed to be?

Comment: @YannickK because the focus function gets called sooner than after 3 seconds. But only after the first time.

Comment: Try to prove it with console.time()

Comment: @KaiLehmann don't know why but I can't seem to console.time/console.log from my react component. Doesn't it suffice if I say that it focusses immediately after I send the fourth or fifth text to the bot?

Comment: Have you tried to make the variable time global and just after setting the input to "" to do a time.clearInterval();? 
I guess your timeout is never cleared and it's overlapping with the local variable

More info: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Comment: @AntonioCalvente tried it before by clearing the timeout after executing but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Yep, I saw the edits of the issue. However, I'm referring to clear previous timeouts that may have been triggered before (that's why I refer to a global variable for the timeout). In you test, you tried to clear it just after setting it :)

Comment: You have to use it outside your react component. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342242/console-log-isnt-logging-in-reactjs

Comment: @KaiLehmann console logging issue is because of this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15398#issuecomment-402332899 but that is not the issue... I can't use debug because of php chat server issues otherwise

Comment: @AntonioCalvente tried it by defining it as a global variable but that didn't work as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for my issue. It appears that the problem had something to do with the `focus()` / `blur()` methods. I used a `disable = true` and `disable = false` and `focus()` after the 3 second delay and now the delay is always 3 seconds.

Code now looks like this:

```js
handleKeyPress = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && this.input.value.replace(/\s/g, "")) {
        this.input.disabled = true;
        this.say(this.input.value);
        // Reset input value
        this.input.value = "";
        this.enable((document.getElementById('userText') as HTMLInputElement));
    }
};

enable = (element: HTMLInputElement) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        element.disabled = false;
        element.focus();
    }, 3000);
};
```